# Как снова запустить таймер CountDownTimer после того, как он был остановлен

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Есть таймер и метод, который запускает  его. 
В процессе работы приложения пользователь вводит некие данные в поле edittext1 и нажимает ввод. С этим все понятно, т.к. все дальнейшие события описаны в методе onKey.

Но вот если пользователь не успевает вести данные и нажать клавишу ввод, таймер останавливается, и должны происходить следующие события:

- поле edittext1 становится недоступным;
- фокус перемещается на поле edittext2;
- таймер начинает новый отсчет

С последним условием проблема. Пыталась в методе onFinish после `editText2.requestFocus();` писать timer.start();, или `showTimer(SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);`, однако таймер начинает новый отсчет, заканчивает его и запускается вновь бесконечное количество раз (что, в принципе, и понятно).
Код:

```
CountDownTimer timer;
int MILLIS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
int SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN = 6;
showTimer(SECONDS_TO_COUNTDOWN * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);

private void showTimer(int countdownMillis) {
    if(timer != null) { timer.cancel(); }
    timer = new CountDownTimer(6000, MILLIS_PER_SECOND) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text_d1.setText("осталось: " +
                    millisUntilFinished / MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (editText1.requestFocus()) {
                editText1.setEnabled(false);
                editText2.requestFocus(); // и счетчик снова запускается
            }else if (editText2.requestFocus()) {
                editText2.setEnabled(false);
                editText3.requestFocus();
            }else {}
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Полей ввода у вас, небось, много будет, не два, а порой ещё и неизвестное заранее количество?..

Comment: вообще да, немало, аж целых 25))) Поэтому код будет "индусский", но я же еще только учусь, мне можно.

Comment: Не надо плохого кода. просто продумайте алгоритм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте список/массив для хранения всех полей ввода.
2. Создайте переменную-счётчик для указания текущего активного поля ввода.
3. В `onFinish` получайте текущее поле ввода из списка по значению счётчика. Отмените его  `setEnabled(false);`, получите следующее (если оно есть, т.е. проверьте не является ли текущее последним), и на него переведите фокус: `listOfEditTexts.get(counter++).requestFocus();`. Теперь просто стартуйте таймер: `timer.start();`

**P.S.**
Обратите внимание на инкрементацию счётчика при вызове следующего поля ввода.